# TFS - ignore the .tpignore lock issue

Tags: tfs, ignore

When a team working on projects, sometimes we failed to ignore specific files.

The reason is the first user who ignore a file lock `.tpignore` file which prevent other user(s) to ignore files

We currently don't use [Enable multiple checkout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

What is the best practice to avoid such issue in TFS 2010?

It seems that `.tpignore` should be part of the version, so is there any other option except moving to multiple checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, enable multiple checkout. Lock-based checkouts are an ancient relic of bad version control systems. If you have an undiffable binary file, that's one thing, but source code and configuration files that can be diffed should never be exclusively locked.

Even better, upgrade to a modern version of TFS and use local workspaces (or migrate to Git). Local workspaces are supported in TFS 2012 and beyond and are considered better than server workspaces in most scenarios.